# Predictors that are integers and factor types in a linear model

Tags: r, regression, predictor, categorical-encoding

I am running a hierarchical linear regression. My predictors consist of both continuous and categorical variables. R treats the continuous variables as integers, and I have converted the categorical variables from character to factors, which I had dummy coded (not binomially). Thus, my predictor/covariates are age (continuous), gender (factor; 3 levels), religion (factor; 7 levels), SES (factor; 4 levels), location (grouping factor; 3 levels).

I read on another Stack Exchange post to look at the R^2 when treating each variable as integer or factor. The R^2 was always larger when treating the predictor as a factor. This leads me to think that this would be the appropriate step for the analysis. However, the outputs of the model show the significance of all levels of each factor. If I continue treating the predictors as factors, how would I interpret the outputs given the significance of one level of a factor predictor? (P.S. the DV for the model is performance on a test.)

Comment: I believe you mean "real numbers" when you say "integers." Integers can be only 0, 1, 2, ... or their negatives.

Comment: @RussLenth I mean that the variable types are int, which I presume to be an integer type variable.

Comment: Unless your factors are ordered it makes zero sense to use their internal integer encoding for regression. R² values do not matter here. You could make a case for using integer encoded age classes (although polynomial contrasts seem preferable) but religion always needs dummy encoding.

Comment: Maybe that is a characteristic of your own data, but the statement that "R treats continuous variables as integers" is false.